# Inconsistent handling of "no further action" for disputed flags

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, flags

When selecting *no further action* on a disputed flag on `/admin/dashboard`, it is immediately removed from the list, and there is no way to mark it helpful or decline it.

However, when viewing the flagged question or answer and selecting *no further action* there, the dialog presenting further options is shown.

One of these should be changed to behave like the other, or one of the button labels should be changed to indicate that a different action is performed.

Comment: Are you sure we want consistency here? Right now we have the option of either quickly removing flags from the queue, or marking them as helpful/declining them.  If they're made to behave the same, we lose one of those options.

Comment: @BilltheLizard It doesn't behave like a feature IMO. If it really is a feature, there should at least be an indicator that it behaves differently depending on where you handle the flag (differently labeled buttons perhaps).